# Overlapped text and page number in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, overlap

My table of contents was created by LaTeX however, the description and page number overlap each other shown in the folowing figure.

[image]

Here are my codes;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
 % Some extra symbols
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\includeonly{introduction} % To only process the given file
%% Additional Ones
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-9cm-4\tabcolsep}
\newcommand*{\nl}{\newline}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2.\hfill}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\makemstitle % M.S. thesis
\makeapprovalpage
\begin{acknowledgements}
\end{acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}
\begin{ozet} 
\end{ozet}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\begin{abbreviations}
\end{abbreviations}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT, TOTAL TRANSLATION AND TOTAL MODEL TRANSLATION SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

\end{document}
```

How can I overcome this conflict?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code that shows the problem, what's your document class, which packages you load, &c.?

Comment: We do not have `fbe_tez.sty`. If I remove this package and the undefined commands (`\makemstitle` etc.), I can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Off-topic: you really, really should do something about that preamble. I'd frankly expect problems here.